# Varnish stats only for pages

Tags: varnish

On my server I'm usign Varnish 3.
If I run "varnishstats" I can view stats, but the count of "missed" and "hits" is related to *every* resource served by Varnish.
Is there a way to obtain stats ONLY for "pages"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `varnishstat` does not support any filtering.